# How to implement OnAppear functionality in a custom component inside a native-base Tabs component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a native base tab bar where I show a different page for each tab.

```js
 <Tabs>
   <Tab
     heading="FirstTab"
     activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
     activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
   >
     <MyCustomeComponent/>
   </Tab>
   <Tab
     heading="SecondTab"
     activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
     activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
   >
     <MyOtherCustomeComponent/>
   </Tab>
```

Now I want to kick off a function in `MyCustomeComponent` and `MyOtherCustomeComponent` whenever the correspongin Tab is selected. Something like a OnAppear functionality.

I know that there is the `onChangeTab` property from the `Tabs` component but I have no idea how to get into my custom component from there.

Comment: do you mean that, you want to pass some info in your custom component ?

Answer (score 1):

try react-native-tab-view. Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view)

Hope this will help you.

Update:

You have to add a "ref" to your Tabs and then use "this.refs". Your code will look like this:

```
checkTabPosition(e){
    // determine which tab to refresh
    var tabToRefresh = ...;

    // refresh tab
    refreshTab(tabToRefresh);
}

refreshTab( tab ){
  this.refs[tab].fetchData();
}
```

Then, call it from "onChangeTab"

```
<Tabs onChangeTab={(e)=>{this.checkTabPosition(e)}}>
    <Tab
         ref="tab1"
         heading="FirstTab"
         activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
         activeTextStyle={styles.activeTextStyle}
    >
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there another way? 
I don't want to add another external component for that.

Comment: thanks, I used refs for that. Its still not pretty but it works